# Could I write a library such that when loaded it first generates a dataset which could later be accessed by other functions?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

Normally libraries' functions are only executed when called (unlike normal program which has an entry point like `main()`), but in this case I would like to ship a library that requires a data set, which the data set is too big that's it'll be better to generate on its own.

Which makes me wonder could I write a library that when loaded, executes a function that generates the data set (perhaps saving in global variable or an `extern` variable) which can later be used by other functions, something like following:

```cpp
// lib.hh
#pragma once
struct Data{}; // Data is a custom class for holding the data set
extern Data dataset;
```

```cpp
// lib.cc
#include"./lib.hh"
Data gen() {
    // Generates the data here
    return result;
}
double find(double key) {
    // Searches data within `dataset` that has `key` as its key
}
```

So when loaded in another program, `gen()` should run automatically (and prior to any other functions), which then the program that loaded the library could call `find(double)`.

Is such library implementation possible? Or should I better just summon a child process that generates the data, then retrieve results through pipe?

Comment: Seems you want some async functions and retrieve the data via future object(it will blocks if the async function hasn't finished)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cases like this I would recommend to use a *static local variable*

```
//header
struct Data{
Data() {
//Complex intialization code goes here
}
};


Data& data_gen() {
    static Data data;
    return data;
}

//caller/main
auto Data = data_gen(); //Initialization code run once
auto Data2 = data_gen(); //Reuse the variable no more runs
```

Even different threads can call that `data_gen` function, but of course they should only read it never write something unsynchronized. So I would generally give out a const reference to it, since sharing mutable data i.e. state via globals is very very bad style.
So prefer

```
const Data& data_gen() {
    static Data data;
    return data;
}
```

But although that approach is the most robust one, often you can just let it run before the main function runs, if you are a so called statically linked (the classic/default/standardized way in C++), but not if you are a .so/.dll/.dylib:

```
//Header lib.hpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
namespace lib_name {

    struct Data{
        Data() {
            std::cout << "Ctor\n";
        }
        double find(double key) const{
            return 0;
        }
    };
    extern const Data dataset;

    void foo();
}

//lib.cpp
#include <lib.hpp>

namespace lib_name {
    const Data dataset;

    void foo() {
        dataset.find(5);
    }

}
//main
#include <lib.hpp>
int main() {
    lib_name::dataset.find(4.2);
    lib_name::dataset.find(4.2);
    lib_name::foo();
}
```

You will get only one "Ctor", before the main, but if your data generating is complex but can be done with `std::array` why not make it even easier?

```
//header
#include <array>

namespace lib_name {

    struct Data{
        constexpr Data() {
            d_[0] = 42;
        }
        double find(size_t key) const{
            return d_.at(key);
        }

        std::array<double,5> d_{};
    };
    inline constexpr Data dataset;

    void foo();//just for demonstration optional of course
}

//lib.cpp optional
#include <lib.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace lib_name {
    void foo() {
        std::cout << dataset.find(0) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Then your initialization code is run once, but by the compiler on compilation. It then just saves the result.

Comment: The very first example did what I just want, but from my knowledge doesn't `static` requires each TU to obtain a copy of the variable? Then I doesn't see memory usage increase as I called different time? If I understand correctly, is it that the function `data_gen` is optimized out by compiler such that they all point to the same copy? As normally when you called a function twice, it shouldn't reuse the variable from the previous run right?

Comment: No in the first and second example you will have exactly one copy in your process. In the third example IIRC the compiler will decide.

Comment: And while your understanding of `static` would in general be right, as they can not have external linkage, its not right for the first example the so called  static local variable. It has static in its name and code but works quite different, since you have to differentiate between static linkage and internal and external linkage.

Comment: Note the added inline for the 3rd example, AFAIK then the compiler makes sure only one copy is in there, as its guarantee to have the same address then. @Andrew.Wolphoe

Comment: (I'm actually planning the lib to be a shared library so I'm implementing your very first example) So it seems that all access are pointed toward the same dataset, but will this still holds if the dataset is being changed? So first we guarantee everything that exists will continue to exists (as we're only appending data later on), and that we'll fence action that retrieves data that aren't generated. Then is it possible for me to generate more data into the dataset in the background as other functions retrieves values (either async or multithreading)?

Comment: Well there is not hidden copy on write semantic in C++ (besides the broken Java oriented Qt library), and if you remove the constexpr and const you could still modify it, but you would have to synchronize any concurrent data access as any shared state. And as I said global variables are bad, premature optimization too. For things like a plugged in device list read about dependency injection, otherwise this whole thing is way beyond scope of this question ;-) Don't forget to mark as accepted ;-)

Comment: And you could call `data_gen` in a `DllMain ` to get it going from the start, even start a detached thread there to call it, but not later non const actions on it. @Andrew.Wolphoe